# Trying to make a calculator with javascript but doesn't give any results

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio

I'm practicing if statements and I'm trying to make a calculator. I can enter the numbers but clicking on the add, subtract, multiply or divide buttons does not give me any results. I know there are easier ways to do it but it was just for practice. What have I done wrong?

```js
function operar(boton) {

  var num1, num2, resultado;

  num1 = document.getElementById("num1");
  num2 = document.getElementById("num2");
  resultado = document.getElementById("resultado");

  if (boton.value == '+') {
    resultado.value = Number(num1.value) + Number(num2.value);
  } else {
    if (boton.value == '-') {
      resultado.value = Number(num1.value) - Number(num2.value);
    } else {
      if (boton.value == '*') {
        resultado.value = Number(num1.value) * Number(num2.value);
      } else {
        if (boton.value == '/') {
          resultado.value = Number(num1.value) / Number(num2.value);

        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <label>Número 1</label>
    <input id="num1" type="text" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Número 2</label>
    <input id="num2" type="text" />
  </div>

  <input type="button" value="+" onclick="operar(this)" />
  <input type="button" value="-" onclick="operar(this)" />
  <input type="button" value="*" onclick="operar(this)" />
  <input type="button" value="/" onclick="operar(this)" />

  <div>
    <label>Resultado</label>
    <input type="text" id="resultado" />
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Works fine here

Answer (score 0):

The snippet you gave here, this code is running perfectly. What else do you want to do?

Comment: I do not get it. I don't know why if I run it from here it works perfectly for me and instead when I open the page in the browser it stops working. Could there be any reason why this happens?

Comment: Can you please give me a console.log() . I think there I can find something.

Comment: I'm still very new to this and I don't know how to do it. Would I have to put console.log() in the js code only or do I have to add the name of the function?

Comment: If anything is wrong the console will show you . But you can log() reading too if you want. Which browser are you working on right now?

Comment: This error is the one that has appeared to me from the Chrome console, I don't know if that's what you were referring to: Uncaught ReferenceError: operar is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (calculadora.html:32:64).

Comment: In this case I would be needing the whole file to inspect to see what is wrong in that line.

Comment: It doesn't let me to add the rest of the code, but these are the only lines missing above the html one: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script type=text/javascrip src="js/calculadora.js"></script>
    <title>Sumar</title>
    
    <style type="text/css">
        div {
            padding:5px;
        }

        input[type="button"] {
            width:52px;
        }
    </style>

</head>